# How to improve the quality of a .png tikz output

Tags: r-markdown, png, bookdown, tikz

I am using `bookdown` in MacOS 10.15, and I have a `tikz` figure which comes out great in PDF, but the PNG version (used by the HTML book) is quite ugly. For instance, some parallel lines of same length have different apparent thickness (even though they are drawn with identical parameters).

How can I improve the quality of the produced PNG?

Answer (score 1):

Use chunk option `fig.ext='svg'` to get better picture quality

Comment: Thanks! I would love to get 'svg' to work, but I am getting empty files so far, cf.: https://community.rstudio.com/t/empty-svg-files/144056

Comment: can you try with `fig.ext="pdf"` then?

Comment: as I said above, PDF comes out fine, but the HTML book can't use PDF